# How to transform a dataframe based on if,else conditions?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to build a function which transform a dataframe based on certain conditions but I am getting a Systax Error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd  
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
df=pd.read_csv('example1.csv')
df.columns =(['dtime','kW'])
df['dtime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dtime'])
df.head(5)
           dtime        kW
0   2019-08-27 23:30:00 0.016
1   2019-08-27 23:00:00 0
2   2019-08-27 22:30:00 0.016
3   2019-08-27 22:00:00 0.016
4   2019-08-27 21:30:00 0

def transdf(df):
    a=df.loc[0,'dtime']
    b=df.loc[1,'dtime']
    c=a-b
    minutes = c.total_seconds() / 60
    d=int(minutes)
    #d can be only 15 ,30 or 60
    if d==15:
        return df=df.set_index('dtime').asfreq('-15T',fill_value='Missing')
    elif d==30:
        return df=df.set_index('dtime').asfreq('-30T',fill_value='Missing')
    elif d==60:
        return df=df.set_index('dtime').asfreq('-60T',fill_value='Missing')
    else:
        return None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first. It is more efficient to have the return statement after the else at the end of your code. Inside each of the cases just update the value for df. Return is part of your function, not the if statement that's why you are getting errors.

```
def transform(df):
 a = df.loc[0, 'dtime']
 b = df.loc[1, 'dtime']
 c = a - b
 minutes = c.total_seconds() / 60
 d=int(minutes)
 #d can be only 15 ,30 or 60
 if d==15:
   df= df.set_index('dtime').asfreq('-15T',fill_value='Missing')
 elif d==30:
   df= df.set_index('dtime').asfreq('-30T',fill_value='Missing')
 elif d==60:
   df= df.set_index('dtime').asfreq('-60T',fill_value='Missing')
 else:
   None
 return dfere
```